# Dismissing Modal View Controller causing layout problems

Tags: ipad, layout, uiscrollview, modalviewcontroller

I have a UIScrollVIew in a Navigation controller, I present a Modal View controller from the Navigation controller, which works fine.  When I dismiss the modal view controller (from the parent), all the content in my UIScroll view gets moved around and paging is broken.  The contents of the scroll view are added programmatically, but the scrollView was created in IB.

Comment: What happens in the UIScrollView controller's viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, viewWillDissappear, viewDidDissappear?

Comment: I had the same issue so I added the viewWillAppear method and put in an NSLog and it turned out the ScrollView was getting longer after the Modal View Controller disappeared.  Not sure why but I reset the ScrollView frame at this point and it's now working

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like it has to do with autoresizing behavior as well as the autoresizing masks. In IB, turn off "Autoresize Subviews" in relation to the ScrollView.

Also check its autoresizing mask: does it make sense? Play with its mask and trouble shoot from there. When you create views programmatically, the default autoresize mask may have unexpected behavior.

Comment: You, Sir, just gave me the solution to two days of researching why my transitions screwed up my layout. It had nothing to do with my fancy 3D stuff or whatever, just adding `self.contentScrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO` did the trick. Two and a half years later, I want to express you my gratitude.