# When Dismissing a Modal View Controller the underlying UIScrollView resizes to fullscreen

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, modalviewcontroller

I have a layout with a custom status bar on top [below Apple's status bar], then a `UIScrollview` that paginates left to right in the middle section, and then I have a `UIView` with some custom buttons on the bottom.  So a simple three-paned layout, and it works great.  However, the three custom buttons on the lower view bring up a `ModalViewController`, and when that is dismissed, it resizes the middle `UIScrollView` to full-screen, and brings it to the front, covering the other two views that I have.

There are several others who have noted this behavior, but it seems that the only answers they are given is to re-resize the `UIScrollView` back to the original coordinates.  This will work, of course, but it seems like a hack to me, and I would like ot know what is really going on behind the scenes here, and how to rectify the issue correctly.

Other SO links with the same apparent issue:

- [Dismiss modal view changes underlying UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168682/dismiss-modal-view-changes-underlying-uiscrollview)
- [Dismissing Modal View Controller causing layout problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747566/dismissing-modal-view-controller-causing-layout-problems)
- [Weird Behavior on dismissing Modal View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554768/weird-behavior-on-dismissing-modal-view-controller)

Still others have noted that the behavior only affects 3.0 and up, so I am not sure if this is a "feature," and I am just not understanding what the behavior is supposed to be doing, or what.  If anyone can shed some light on this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem.
In the parent of the modal view, I'm using this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight)];
}
```

where originalWidth & originalHeight are the original sizes of my parent view.

it works fine, even if it sounds like a hack to me too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change setting in nib files.?

Check the autosizing of scroll view in nib.

Comment: I changed the autosizing settings, and it didn't seem to change anything.  Thanks!